# Expand the list available for "Close --> Off topic --> belongs on another site on SE"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With respect to [this motorbike question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51594/black-smoke-pulsar150-2013-37000kms-no-oil-leakage)  its clearly off-topic here and would be suitable on *mechanics*

When we vote to close a question as off topic for Bicycles, there is an option to nominate a stack where it is on topic.

[image]

[image]

Can we have these other stacks listed, to facilitate forwarding a question:

- https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/
- https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/
- https://travel.stackexchange.com/

I considered listing https://law.stackexchange.com/  and https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com but they're not that common.

Comment: Note that direct migration path is only possible from/to graduated sites which only [mechanics.se], [travel.se] and [law.se] are. Also, consider asking on their meta sites whether they *allow* being the target for direct migration path, because unlike manual migration by mod, it's instant (but as always,
 [**don't migrate crap**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/241919)).

Comment: @AndrewT. you make an excellent point; the example question was probably a duplicate of something on mechanics.

Comment: @Criggie - Also, it's only 10k+ users that get the list. Everyone else only gets the meta option as I understand it.

Comment: Several years later are there any changes that would make this possible?  travel/mechanics/electronics/physics would all be helpful for migration votes.
I added a comment to the linked question 2 years ago but no response